# Queryble filtered KTable

Tags: apache-kafka, aggregation, apache-kafka-streams

Here is a sample `KTable` that I've built which is a straightforward aggregation:

```
String name = stream
    .groupByKey()
    .aggregate(
        () -> new Aggregate(config),
        (key, value, aggregate) -> aggregate.addAndReturn(value),
        Materialized
            .<String, Aggregate>as(Stores.inMemoryKeyValueStore(config.OutputStore()))
            .withCachingEnabled()
            .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
            .withValueSerde(CustomSerdes.ObjectSerde()))
    .filter(((key, value) -> value.isStateChanged()))
    .filter((key, value) -> !value.getRecentlyViewed().isEmpty())
    .queryableStoreName();
```

What I need to do is to store the final `KTable`(after filtering applied) in the state store rather than the initial `KTable`. Currently `KTable.queryableStoreName()` returns `null`.

My current solution is to apply `filter()`, then convert to stream using `KTable.toStream()` and finally store as `KTable` again which I think it's inefficient. Is there any other solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enforce the materialization of a `KTable` by providing a queryable store name:

```java
.aggregate()
.filter(..., Materialized.as("your-custom-store-name"));
```

Depending on the version you are using, you might need to specify some generics to make it compile:

```java
Materialized<KEY_TYPE, VALUE_TYPE, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>.as("your-custom-store-name"))
```

Comment: `aggregate` still enforces materialization anyways. I need a way to bypass materialization and just do it once after `filter`. https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/javadocs/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KGroupedStream.html#aggregate-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Initializer-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Aggregator-

Comment: Let me quote it here:

For failure and recovery the store will be backed by an internal changelog topic that will be created in Kafka. The changelog topic will be named "${applicationId}-${internalStoreName}-changelog", where "applicationId" is user-specified in StreamsConfig via parameter APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "internalStoreName" is an internal name and "-changelog" is a fixed suffix. Note that the internal store name may not be queriable through Interactive Queries. You can retrieve all generated internal topic names via Topology.describe().

Comment: That is not possible -- an aggregation is a stateful operator and needs its own store. It cannot compute the aggregation without a store.